# Is there a way to avoid using a lot of many to many relationships in my database?

Tags: mysql, database, model

I am currently trying to create a database for a shopping webapp with both shopping list and recipes, but i have read that you should avoid many to many relations at all costs, i am finding myself in the situation that i have a lot of them.

I am just wondering if any of you have any tips on how to manage or what i can do about it. Or should i just leave it the way it is?

[Database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3kOV.png)

Comment: *I have read that you should avoid many to many relations at all costs* - That is nonsense!

Comment: You should read better sources on database design.  And learn about normalization and junction tables.